# Place API Error: Unhandled exceptions

Tags: android, google-places-api

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
startActivityForResult(builder.build(MainActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

I'm using this source code , but there's an error at `builder.build(MainActivity.this)` like this:

> Unhandled exceptions: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException, com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException

I checked that it's feature API(`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'` on `bulid.gradle`). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable/update/upgrade google play services on your phone.

As it is written in [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) the best solution on production phase is:

> GooglePlayServicesRepairableExceptions are special instances of UserRecoverableExceptions which are thrown when Google Play Services is not installed, up-to-date, or enabled. In these cases, client code can use getConnectionStatusCode() in conjunction with getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity, int, int) to provide users with a localized Dialog that will allow users to install, update, or otherwise enable Google Play services.

Comment: On my phone...? It's on compile. like this : `Error:(55, 53) error: unreported exception GooglePlayServicesRepairableException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

Comment: Be more specific Next time

Answer (score 0):

This is happend because your play services is not uptodate... 
below code will show a dialog box to the user for updating Play Services

```
 Int status;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                        100).show();
            } 
        }
}
```